# How do I maximise and minimize the mathematical expression using recursion?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

Expression consists of numbers (0-9) seperated by one of the two operators '`*`' and '`+`'. There are no spaces between the characters.

Example: `1+2*3+4*5`

We need to find out the maximum and minimum value we can get by using brackets at appropriate places.

Maximum value:`105 = (1+2)*(3+4)*5`

Minimum value:  `27  = 1+2*3+4*5`

I am looking for a recursive way to do it? Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the number of brackets we should use fixed ?

Comment: 1+(2*3)+4*5 and other variants are also a minimum

Comment: @MrGreen: No it is not fixed. You can add as much as you want. Problem is that what will be the maximum value you can achieve.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: it doesn't matter in all cases minimum value is 27.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Minimization**:

The main idea of the solution: instead of thinking how to add parentheses, let's think about which operation was the last one. Let's write a recursive function `minimize(expr)`. What should it do? If it is given one number, it should just return it. Otherwise, we can iterate over all operators in it, call `minimize` for the part expression to the left and to the right of the operator and combine the result. Now we just need to pick the smallest value.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
int minimize(string expr)
    if isNumber(expr) then // If it is one number, return it.
        return value(expr)
    int res = infinity
    for int i <- 0 .. lenght expr - 1
        if expr[i] == '+' then
            res = min(res, minimize(expr[0 .. i - 1]) +
                           minimize(expr[i + 1 .. length expr - 1])
        if expr[i] == '*' then
            res = min(res, minimize(expr[0 .. i - 1]) * 
                           minimize(expr[i + 1 .. length expr - 1])
    return res
```

**Maximization**:

Pretty much the same, but we should take maximum instead of minimum at each step.

Why is it correct? When we multiply and add non-negative numbers, the larger(the smaller) the operands are, the larger(the smaller) the result is.

We can also use memoization to avoid recomputing result for the same expression twice(or more times) and obtain polynomial time complexity.